# Getting undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass only with RubyMine debugger on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, intellij-idea, rubymine

My environment:

```
Ubuntu 14
Ruby 2.2.1
Rails 4.2
```

Newly created rails application, with 1 action:

```
class FramesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    return 0
  end
end
```

Wherever I put a breakpoint (in presented case at return 0), I get this error in my browser:

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

It only happens when I use the 'Debug' option in RubyMine and when a breakpoint is reached. When I run the server without debugger/breakpoints, everything works fine.

Comment: Have you tried using something like `raise` instead of `return 0` as the breakpoint? I have a feeling that returning the number 0 here is causing problems with Rails controller conventions that you can't see.

Comment: I ended up with return 0 after I have tried a lot of different code. For example, calling sub on a string. The error is always the same but only with debugger on and a breakpoint. It runs fine otherwise.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same issue, and just removing the `byebug gem` from the **Gemfile** fixed it

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  #gem 'byebug'
```

Check if you have the **byebug** in the **Gemfile** and in case disable it.

Tested with Intellij Idea 14.1, should also apply to RubyMine

Comment: It seemed to have done something. I no longer get the error on breakpoint but I'm afraid I might have messed up my gems in the meanwhile because now the debugger doesn't stop at all at breakpoints. Which gems does RubyMine require for the debugger to work?

Comment: I guess it's ruby-debug-ide. list the try to restart the editor as this can help. Check if there are any updates that you have to install to rubymine or to the plugins and there was something fixed and released just today.

Comment: The classic "have you tried turning it off and on again?" fixed it for me. Thank you :)

Comment: had `pry-byebug` installed. removing it from the Gemfile fixed that same error for me